# Canvas.Tag_bind not working with OOP | Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have recently been learning the object-oriented way of programming in python and I'm struggling with this simple task when dealing with canvas. The solution is probably very simple but I can't work it out

My Code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
canvas = Canvas(frame, width=500, height=500)
frame.pack()
canvas.pack()


class Game:
    def __init__(self, root, frame, canvas):
        self.root = root
        self.frame = frame
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = self.canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30)
        self.canvas.bind(self.id, 'a', self.update)

    def update(self):
        print('yasssss')


g = Game(root, frame, canvas)
root.mainloop()
```